# Does Symfony2 detect cyclical dependencies between services?

Tags: php, symfony, service, factory

Say you need to build a complex service relying on other services in Symfony2. One way to create these services is to create factories.

Yet, is it possible to create services with cyclical dependencies to other services in Symfony2 or not? I know this is not a good coding practice, but that is not my question.

Should one implement service `setter` methods as mentioned in the documentation to enable this? Else, how does Symfony2 deals with these chicken and egg issues? Does it throw an error?

Comment: The Symfony dependency injection container will throw an exception when it detects circular dependencies.

Comment: If you are interested in how it works, you can take a look at the [CheckCircularReferencesPass](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckCircularReferencesPass.php) from the DependencyInjection component

Comment: @Cerad If you create an answer, I'll approve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out is to try it:

1). [Install a Symfony standard edition application](http://symfony.com/download)

I installed **Symfony 2.8.1** for this example.

2). In the default AppBundle add the following files in `Services` folder:

`ServiceA.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class ServiceA
{
    private $service;

    public function __construct(ServiceB $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
}
```

`ServiceB.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class ServiceB
{
    private $service;

    public function __construct(ServiceA $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
}
```

3). Add an extension subclass in `DependencyInjection` folder:

`AppExtension.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

4). And declare the circular-dependent services in `Resources` folder:

`services.yml`:

```
services:
    service_a:
        class: AppBundle\Services\ServiceA
        arguments:
            - @service_b

    service_b:
        class: AppBundle\Services\ServiceB
        arguments:
            - @service_a
```

After all this, if you run `php app/console --version`, you will get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]
Circular reference detected for service "service_a", path: "service_a -> service_b -> service_a".
```